# heap allocation returned from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, new-operator

```
The function has a problem: 

void myAllo(int mySize, char *myChar )
{
    myChar = new char[mySize];
}
```

Will the heap allocation be returned from `myAllo()` ? 
I do not think so, because memory pointed by `myChar` will 
be deallocated when `myAllo` returns.

Right ?

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: `myChar` is a parameter, and as such a local variable. It will cease to exist when the function returns, and it will not transfer the value back. This is your problem. You'll have to return something or use a reference.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a well worded question with a code sample to clarify the question.

Answer (score 10):

> > Will the heap allocation be returned from myAllo() ?

No. The argument `myChar` is being passed by value to `myAllo()`, so you're simply modifying a local copy of the pointer, not the value of the pointer in the caller's context.

> > memory pointed by myChar will be deallocated when myAllo returns.

No again. The function leaks the allocated memory when it exits. To de-allocate memory you need to call `delete[]` on the pointer returned by `new[]` but this pointer goes out of scope when the function exits.

---

There are several ways to fix your problem.

Have the caller pass in the address of the pointer which will point to the allocated memory, now you can modify what the caller's pointer points to.

```
void myAllo(int mySize, char **myChar )
{
    *myChar = new char[mySize];
}
```

Similarly, your function could accept a mutable reference to the pointer

```
void myAllo(int mySize, char *& myChar )
{
    myChar = new char[mySize];
}
```

Return a pointer to the allocated memory

```
char *myAllo( int mySize )
{
    return new char[mySize];
}
```

Better than all of the above solutions, instead of returning raw pointers, return a smart pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> myAllo( int mySize )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<char[]>( new char[mySize] );
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`  I don't know if that compiles, but if it does, it leads to undefined behavior, as it will be allocated with `new[]`, and deallocated with `delete` (no []).  Use `std::vector<char>` instead

Comment: @MooingDuck No, `std::unique_ptr` has a partial specialization for `unique_ptr<Type[]>` which calls `delete[]` in the destructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Actually, no, unique_ptr is wise to arrays, although I agree, `vector<char>` would be better.

Comment: I keep forgetting unique_ptr != auto_ptr.  I didn't know about the Type[] overload.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Specialization, not overload.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the heap allocation be returned from myAllo() ?

No.

> memory pointed by myChar will be deallocated when myAllo returns.

No, this is a memory leak.

Comment: It is only a memory leak if there is no matching `delete[]` in the rest of his code.

Comment: @Rob: How could there be a matching `delete[]`?  The pointer is local, it's value is lost.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the memory you allocated you need to write the function as

```
void myAllo(int mySize, char **myChar )
{
    *myChar = new char[mySize];
}
```

and call it

```
char* pointer;
myAllo(size, &pointer);
```

---

or as

```
char* myAllo(int mySize )
{
    return new char[mySize];
}
```

and call it

```
char* pointer = myAllo(size);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void myAllo(int mySize, char *myChar ) 
{   //note: myChar is a COPY of someone else's pointer 
    myChar = new char[mySize];
    //nobody outside of the function will ever see this change
}
```

Dynamic memory (new) is only released when you explicitly release it.
myChar goes out of scope and is automatically cleaned up, but a pointer's "clean up" does *not* deallocate any memory it points at.  This allows me to have multiple pointers point at the same data.

```
void myAllo(int mySize, char *&myChar )
{  //note: myChar is a REFERENCE of someone else's pointer 
    myChar = new char[mySize];
}
```

Or better yet, use a vector:

```
std::vector<char> myAllo(int mySize)
{
    return std::vector<char>(mySize);
}
```

Comment: I prefer your comments on the flagrant missteps in myAllo(..).